# How to retreive key value from JQ via bash script

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq

I am trying to retrieve a key value from aws cli response via jq in shell script however not getting the intended response.

could you please help figure how to retrieve the desired key in below condition

```
resource=aws lambda add-permission --function-name $functionName --statement-id "testing" --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --principal "events.amazonaws.com" --source-arn $rulearn
echo ${resource} | jq ".[]"
```

this return me a response like

```
 {\"Sid\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":\"events.amazonaws.com\"},\"Action\":\"lambda:InvokeFunction\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxx:function:xxxxxx\",\"Condition\":{\"ArnLike\":{\"AWS:SourceArn\":\"arn:aws:events:us-west-2:xxxxxx:rule/xxxxx\"}}}"
```

I am trying to get value of resource using below line

```
   echo ${resource} | jq ".[]" | jq ".Resource"
```

however response is coming back as

```
[
  133
]
```

What should be the correct way to retrieve value of key resource.

Comment: The awscli also has native support for retrieving individual attributes from the JSON output. See the --query option (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter).

Answer (score 1):

The JSON included in the question is a JSON string (except that the initial double-quote is missing).  To convert it into a JSON object, you can use the `fromjson` filter, so you would write:

```
 jq 'fromjson|.Resource'
```

With the given JSON string (with the initial double-quote) as input, this produces:

```
"arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxx:function:xxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Resource` field seems to be in the root object so running `echo ${resource} | jq ".Resource"` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like below:-

Made resource outputted in text format

```
resource=$(aws lambda add-permission --function-name $functionName --statement-id "xxxxxx" --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --principal "events.amazonaws.com" --source-arn $rulearn --query 'Statement' --output text )
```

and then converted it to json using  below and then retreived resource

```
resource=$(echo ${resource} | jq "." | jq ".Resource" | sed "s|\"||g")
```

Comment: You should be able to collapse the three invocations (of jq and sed) to one invocation of jq: jq -r .Resource